# GParted can't resize partition, but unallocated partition is available

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, gparted

I have few partition like this:

[image: GParted]

And I want to take the **unallocated** partition and resize it to **/dev/sda12**.
But when I try to do that:

[image: Resize button isn't enabled]

I can't increase the size.

I have do it in **Live Mode**, and I have tried to the others partition, but still can't do it.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What is your real goal. You end up having to move just about every other partition right to make unallocated next to sda12. You do have a lot of smaller partitions with not a lot of data. Do you need all those as then it makes it more difficult to manage unused space in each partition. What is sda12?

Comment: @oldfred i want to install a game in /home, but my partition is not enough space to do that, so i try to increase my /home partition which is on /dev/sda12.

Comment: You can make another ext4 partition, and mount it at /home/$USER/games. Then you have your space in /home but actually in another partition. There just is a trade off with too many partitions and too few.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partitions need to be exactly above or below the unallocated space to get resized. Here you can extend only sda15, sda5, sda8, sda9 & sda10 partitions. Moreover unlike Windows Ubuntu can't work on dynamic disks, so it is impossible to extend the partition using the partition which is very ***far***.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the existing partitions so that the unallocated space that you wish to use is adjacent to the target partition.  See:
https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual#gparted-resize-partition